# C#: WPF, How to solve threading issues when linking events in dynamically created object to the parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, events

I'm creating a display element that displays the contents of a directory, I want to be able to change the directory currently being displayed, and to be able to have click events on the files, The files and directories are being displayed in the form of `usercontrols`.

I add these custom user controls to a listbox from the parent control using the following code

```
private void UpdateFolder(StorageMethods.UDirectory sourceDir)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.FolderDisplay.Items.Clear()));
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.currentDirectory = sourceDir));
            int i = 0;
            foreach (StorageMethods.UDirectory subDir in sourceDir.subDirs)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.FolderDisplay.Items.Add(new DirItem(subDir, i))));
                i++;
            }
            foreach (StorageMethods.UFile file in sourceDir.files)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.FolderDisplay.Items.Add(new DirItem(file, i))));
                i++;
            }
        }
```

However, this doesn't subscribe the parent to the `DirItem'`s click event.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
DirItem dI = new DirItem(subDir, i);
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => dI.OnItemClick += Di_OnFolderClick));
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.FolderDisplay.Items.Add(dI)));
```

This creates the `DirItem`, and links the event inside it to the parent control, however, when I pass the new `DirItem` to the `folderDisplay` the dispatcher gives me a threading exception as if I wasn't using the dispatcher at all.
"System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: It is hard to grasp what you are doing from your limited code.

Comment: 1. Make sure you do not have multiple UI threads, that could easily lead to issues. 2. Why are you using ` Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` at all? Most UI applications should use the UI thread for almost everything, while using async/await for slow IO operations.

Comment: You are are really using WPF the hard way here.  Directories should be represented by some non-UI type class (call it `DirItemViewModel`)   You should store these in an `ObservableCollection` object.  Your UI `ListBox` should then bind its `ItemsSource` property to that `ObservableCollection`.  You should set the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property to be some sort of `DataTemplate`, laid out in XAML, that shows a`DirItem` or some other UI bound to a `DirItemViewModel` object.   For clicks, use a button bound to a command.